# Loose Windscreen seal strip 02 Honda Accord

Tags: windshield, seal

I just noticed that on the top of my windscreen I can easily peel back the sealant strip across the entire width of the car and almost pull it out by hand.

1. Is this a major issue?
2. How easy is it to replace?
3. Could this be related to my [water leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/54919/19148) question?

I believe I had the windscreen replaced about 5 years ago, and it is in good shape in general.

Note that I can peel the strip back over 90°.  This picture doesn't show that.

[image]

Comment: Who did the work for windshield replacement? Many places have a lifetime seal warranty on their work (lifetime of the vehicle while you own it). If it goes bad, they should replace the seal under warranty. Least you can do is check with them.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Didn't even think of that.  I should have the paperwork somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Paulster2 I found the paperwork from when 4 years ago my windscreen was replaced, and took the car in to be inspected by that company.  The tech got no closer than 20 feet from my car and said straight away "yep, we'll replace that under warranty".

As an added bonus, because of the way the seal is bonded to the windscreen I also ended up with a new windscreen!